# Web based file manager

Tags: php, open-source

I have been using extplorer http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/

Are there any good alternatives which run on PHP & like extplorer. I am having issues with several folder permissions. ie files that are stored under apache & the ftpuser?

Regards,

Comment: How's that alternative would help you?

Comment: hmm, any other solution to fix above issue then?

Comment: that's more sensible question. While previous one was like "I can't hit a nail, give me another hammer"

Comment: fix the permissions or use suphp

Comment: MONSTA Box is what you're looking for. www.monstahq.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have very usual problem
If you have your webserver running with separate user, you have to set permissions to everyone.
So, take your FTP client and set every catalog to 0777 and file to 0666.

Comment: if i set 777 to all (files and folders) then it should work right?

I cant access certain files / folders created by the ftpuser when apache user is used to read.

Comment: @ToughPal so, as I have said. The purpose of such a permission is to let read these files by everyone

Comment: This solution will introduce unnecessary security risks. Setting all files and folders to readable by all is not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

We have always recommended our clients use: [www.filemanager.net](http://www.filemanager.net)

I guess we must have about 8 or 9 licenses with them by now and the feedback from our clients has always been positive.

They also have a really friendly tech support team who have been first-rate in resolving any queries we have had. Can't say that about many companies these days :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://rosefinch.sourceforge.net/